# Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty

Tags: ros, rviz, ubuntu, python, pointcloud

I'm trying to see a point cloud in Rviz but when I add the topic to de Displays i get an error (Rviz) and in the terminal where i opened Rviz I get the following message:

**Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty**

I'm working with OpenDR, specifically with the 3D object detection module.

**Warning in terminal:**

[image: Warning in terminal]

**Rviz error:**

[image: Rviz error]

I'm trying to see other people's responses with the same issue, I have already tried it everything but this information is not valid for me.

The output of rostopic echo /tf:

### transforms:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1696351719
    nsecs: 943305939
  frame_id: "map"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0**
```

for rostopic echo /opendr/dataset_point_cloud the output is:

```
header: 
  seq: 10053
  stamp: 
    secs: 1696352933
    nsecs:   3319978
  frame_id: ''
points: "<array type: geometry_msgs/Point32, length: 18911>"
channels: "<array type: sensor_msgs/ChannelFloat32, length: 1>"
```

Comment: Please post error messages as text and *not* as screenshots, because images are not text searchable.

Comment: Can you please check the frame id the pointcloud is refered to? Try using `ros2 topic echo /opendr/dataset_point_cloud`.

Comment: @DiegoCarvajal Hi, I'm using ROS1 and when I use echo for /opendr/dataset_point_cloud I get a huge **matrix of numbers** and **x,y,z coordinates** but no information about the frame id. Also, when I use rostopic echo /tf I get the following info: **frame_id: "map"** and **child_frame_id: "base_link"**

Comment: @ARosOpenDR Can you please edit the question and add the output from `rostopic echo /opendr/dataset_point_cloud` and `rostopic echo /tf` so we can check the info.

Comment: The output of `rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py` is more useful than the raw topic output of `/tf`

Comment: @DiegoCarvajal Yes, Done! But for rostopic echo /opendr/dataset_point_cloud the output is so huge that I have to put an image, the data is still up and down the terminal but I try to put both to give you an idea.

Comment: You can use `-n 1 --noarr` to keep it reduced. The raw data isn't of interest

Comment: @Tully I used that and i modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that can_transform is being invoked with an empty string as the frame_id. As there doesn't appear to be any issues with your transform tree it's mostly likely that the data in your dataset that you're playing back does not have the `frame_id` fields properly set.

Comment: How can I set correctly the frame_id fields? I don't understand very good how to do it. When I launch point_cloud_dataset_node.py I get this:                                                  **Downloading KITTI Dataset zip file from ftp://opendrdata.csd.auth.gr/perception/object_detection_3d/opendr_nano_kitti.zip to KITTI**                                     So I suppose that this dataset is set wrong?

Comment: The dataset does not contain that information. It's not complete for your use case. I would recommend using the rosbag API to iterate through the bag files and rewrite the frame_ids before you play them back: There's example scripts at http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook

Comment: To close the loop, your echo of the bag file confirms that the frame_ids are not set which was what I guessed the problem was.